# How do we use autotab in backbone js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbonejs view.

How can I use autotab - basically when someone finishes typing a certain length of characters in one input field, it goes to another input field automatically - in Backbonejs view?

http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/

Basically, how can I integrate the plugin above into backbone js view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins suck, write your own stuff!

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-autotab="4" class="autotab" name="name"></input>
<input type="text" data-autotab="4" class="autotab" name="surname"></input>
```

jQuery

```
var $autotabs = $('input.autotab');
$autotabs.on('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        i = $autotabs.index($this);
    if ($this.data('autotab') === $this.val().length) {
        $this.blur();
        $autotabs.eq(i+1).focus();
    }
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/DACY2/1/

Comment: how do we handle deleting numbers?

Answer (score 0):

ok so this how you do the binding for that plugin

```
$('#area_code, #number1, #number2').autotab_magic().autotab_filter('numeric');
```

at the end of the backbone render function for that view add

```
this.$('#area_code, #number1, #number2').autotab_magic().autotab_filter('numeric');
```

to have the same effect

Comment: in the second line, I think you need to get rid of the '.el' part and just use 'this.$('#area_code, ...'